# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'X' - airflow project

Tags: python, error-handling, configuration, airflow, pytest

I'm currently working on a project using airflow and I encounter an error when I'm trying to run the tests. When I run `pytest` in the root of my project, all of the tests are running, but all of them failed due to the same error :

```
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common.utils'
```

Here `common.utils` isn't find, but it's the same error (with others modules) every time.
I try to isolate a file and modifying it to make the import section ok, but everything I tried wasn't working.

So at this point I think I have an issue with the versions of the dependencies, or with a config file (airflow.cfg ?).

I checked if $AIRFLOW_HOME is set on the root of the project, and it's ok.

To import the modules, I tried several ways using `sys`, `os` or `importlib`, but nothing worked.

Comment: I ruined `export PYTHONPATH=${PWD}` in the days folder, so instead of 43 failling tests, I have 4 failling tests and 1 warning

Comment: The tests that fail are the ones with called the modules of the `springer` modules. It's weird because when a test file call a module located in a folder at the same level as `springer`, it seems working

Comment: If you could provide a [mre], probably in a github repo, it would be easier for others to help debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

adding the source package code into sys.path in the head module

```
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent.absolute()))
```

and import the module from from dags.common.utils